# Batch script to read input text file and make text file for each line of input text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having an Input file in the location `C:/temp/sample.txt`, which consists of one word in each line of the text file. For supporting UI, I need each line to be displayed as text file in front end. So I want a batch script which will produce output as text files for each line of the input text file in the same folder. Can you please suggest whether it is possible to make it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with the "for" command:

```
for /f %i in (input.txt) do echo. > %i
```

*Use %%i in batch files instead of %i.*

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%i in (c:\temp\sample.txt) do echo %%i > c:\temp\%%i.txt
```