# Have a batch create text files based on a list

Tags: batch-file

I've got to create a text file for each PC at my workplace is there a way to have a batch read from a list of PCs in a text file and create a text file for each line of text?

Ex. 
Text File

```
    Computer1
    Computer2
    Computer3
```

I want it to create a computer1.txt, computer2.txt, and computer3.txt, but for a list of about 400 PCs... It seems pretty easy I'm just not sure how to link batch files together. I'm learning! :) Thanks for all your help, as always!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (comps.txt) do (type nul>"%%a.txt")
```

To add a pre-defined text to the file, do something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (comps.txt) do (
  echo This is line 1 of text>"%%a.txt"
  echo This is line 2 of text>>"%%a.txt"
  echo This is line 3 of text>>"%%a.txt"
  echo This is line 4 of text>>"%%a.txt"
)
```

Comment: Thanks again! That does it! Only thing I had issues with was if I was to type different text/numbers I would have to do Number0 >>%%a.txt" putting a space between the number 0 and >>. Other than that it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: `>>"%%a.txt" echo(This is line 1 of text` <-- change the order of redirection to eliminate the need for a space in every line.  The `(` also protects against issues with certain characters at the start of the line

Answer (score 0):

http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

```
FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command
```

See also:
[Batch script to read input text file and make text file for each line of input text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648627/batch-script-to-read-input-text-file-and-make-text-file-for-each-line-of-input-t)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar but different requirement, which was that my file had two columns of data, comma separated.

First col: the file name I wanted

Second col: the data for the contents of that file (HTML)

i.e.:

```
asdf.html, <p>Text about this</p>
bcvadf.html, <p>More text</p>
```

So this was what I put in cmd:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %G in (file.csv) DO echo %H > D:\temp\%G
```

Explanation:

- %G relates to 'token' (column) 1, %H column 2
- 'echo' tell it was to write, in this case column 2 (the content within the file)
- ">" actually creates the file/s
- "> D:\temp\%G" creates the file with the name in the 1st column

Further understanding and examples, as in crownedzero's answer, https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html