# How to create folders and files from text file with same names to insert with corresponding name?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, directory

I was inspired on works of our colleagues from portal

[Have a batch create text files based on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732198/have-a-batch-create-text-files-based-on-a-list)
[Batch script to read input text file and make text file for each line of input text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648627/batch-script-to-read-input-text-file-and-make-text-file-for-each-line-of-input-t)

to develop creation from a text file for example
`"comps.txt" ( comp1,comp2....`
for each PC a batch script read from a list of PCs in a text file and create a text file for each line of text as local.
Later in code are created folders files named - the same names ( comp1,comp2....
at the end we have text files : comp1.txt ,comp2.txt ... and folders: comp1 , comp2.... till 400 computers.
 Any idea how to add in code or write another separate batch  code to move for each coresponding folder text file for text file

```
comp1.txt->comp1 folder  
comp2.txt->comp2.txt  
....
```

We have more than 400 lines!!
I am very begginers for any scrips working very hard every single day  and this is my first question. My code in Windows Batch is below

```
@echo off
  setlocal
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (comps.txt) do (type nul>"%%a.txt")
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (comps.txt) do (
   echo This is line 1 of text>"%%a.txt"
   )
   for /f %%i in (comps.txt) do mkdir %%i 
  do (
  echo "%%i.txt"
      )
  endlocal
```

[[image]]

Comment: How about [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code properly so one can read it??

Comment: I have to find a way and read more how to make more vissible and clear code- I will try

Comment: https://lookimg.com/images/2017/03/16/code.jpg

Comment: https://lookimg.com/images/2017/03/16/externalscreenshoot.jpg

Comment: Dear aschipfl Next time I will read more carefully How to make well seen formatted code- Only screen images above

Comment: Dear aschipfl  I am here for the very first time in my life I thank you for your evaluation. I can't modify in the first place emded code in  asked question to be more  transparent and formatted   .                                                                                              - Only screen images above  :First :Code and 2nd :Result - Not so much  can't modify asked question. Can You Help Me?

Comment: Never saw such weird question for a quite simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to generate text files and then folders to move the files to. Create the folders first place and create the files into the folders. Using a (code block) only one for loop is needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (comps.txt) do (
  if not exist "%%a" mkdir "%%a"
  echo This is line 1 of text>"%%a\%%a.txt"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Many thanks -working perfectly  with your help and code very much . That not  only about txt file- For me that has a sense especially when You  change inside code  extension from " .txt->.bat                                                                                   [echo This is line 1 of text>"%%a\%%a.txt" ->echo This is line 1 of text>"%%a\%%a.bat" ]                                                          and You have computer folder name with same batch script name  for futher modifications    that can be given any variable - I will see Tommorow -time running too fast  -Regards